# ruby on rails regular expression

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm new to regular expressions and i'm feeling this very difficult to solve:

I have a the following string:

```
"inforun 7970 12423 99 10:03 ? 00:09:03 abcd -PR -gmh domain.den.abc.com -gmp 6020 -guid 9c06cc02-b1c8-41cf-93e6-1d795e9fff62 -rst 180 -s FOLDER_NAME:wkf_workflow.s_session -something Session task instance [session]"
```

I have to extract the `time` which `10:03` and the `'domain'` in `domain.den.abc.com` and the `FOLDER_NAME`, the `'workflow'` in the `'wkf_worklfow'` and the `'session'` in the `'s_session'` the `time`, `domain`, `foldername`, `workflow` and `session` keep changing for every string and there are a bunch of strings like this all attached as a single string. 
Here are the patterns that are common for every string. the `'abcd -PR -gmh'` is common and can help in finding the time that is just before the `'?'`
the `'-s', ':wkf'` is common for all the string and the `folder_name` is right in between these two.
the `'workflow'` is in between `'wkf_'` and `'.s_'`
the session is in between `'s_'` and the immediate next `'-'` 
I need the time, domain, folder name, workflow and session all in seperate strings.
I tried to practice regular expression only a few days back it is taking so much time for me even to comprehend something like `"\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z"` which is given [here](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/modeling-and-viewing-users-one#table%3aemail_regex) 
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex (time `$1`, domain `$2`, folder name `$3`, workflow `$4`, session `$5`):

```
(?<=\s)(\d{2}:\d{2})(?=\s).*?(?<=\s)((?:[a-zA-Z\d]+(?:\-[a-zA-Z\d]+)*\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,4})(?=\s).*?(?<=\s)([a-zA-Z\d_]+):wkf_([a-zA-Z\d]+)\.s_([a-zA-Z\d]+)(?=\s)
```

Ruby:

```
text = "inforun 7970 12423 99 10:03 ? 00:09:03 abcd -PR -gmh domain.den.abc.com -gmp 6020 -guid 9c06cc02-b1c8-41cf-93e6-1d795e9fff62 -rst 180 -s FOLDER_NAME:wkf_workflow.s_session -something Session task instance [session]"
text =~ /(?<=\s)(\d{2}:\d{2})(?=\s).*?(?<=\s)((?:[a-zA-Z\d]+(?:\-[a-zA-Z\d]+)*\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,4})(?=\s).*?(?<=\s)([a-zA-Z\d_]+):wkf_([a-zA-Z\d]+)\.s_([a-zA-Z\d]+)(?=\s)/
puts $~.captures
```

Output:

```
10:03
domain.den.abc.com
FOLDER_NAME
workflow
session
```

See and test the code [here](http://ideone.com/q4XvG).

Comment: Hi I dont know if iam doing the right thing, here is my code: string2, string1 = string.scan(/(?<=\s)(\d{2}:\d{2})(?=\s)/) "string" is having the string i posted in the question and iam using string.split string3, string4 = string.scan(/(?<=\s)((?:[a-zA-Z\d]+(?:\-[a-zA-Z\d]+)*\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,4})(?=\s)/) string5, string6, string7 = string.scan(/(?<=\s)([a-zA-Z\d_]+):wkf_([a-zA-Z\d]+)\.s_([a-zA-Z\d]+)(?=\s)/) Obviously iam doing something wrong here please let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's a regex you could use. I'm not familiar enough with Ruby/RoR to help there, but presuming you actually want to use a regex for it, this regex should get you everything in one go

```
^.* (\d\d?:\d\d) \? .*? -gmh (.*?)\..*? -s (.*?):wkf_(.*?)\.s_(.*?) .*$
```

http://regexr.com?31da7 should show the capturing groups and their contents

```
$1    $2     $3          $4       $5
10:03 domain FOLDER_NAME workflow session
```

It presumes the Time is immediately before the question mark and is formatted as digit (optional digit) colon digit digit, that the domain immediately follows '-gmh ', that the folder name follows the -s and precedes the  :wkf_, the workflow follows the :wkf_, and that the session is after the .s_

Comment: Hi, I have multiple strings like the above, combined as one string. Your expression works but prints only the last pattern it comes across

Comment: You'd have to find a way to split the strings apart and run this on each then?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using ruby 1.9, here's a starting point:

```
/(?<time>\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}) abcd -PR -gmh (?<domain>[a-zA-Z]*)/i =~ s
/-s (?<folder_name>\w*):wkf_(?<workflow>\w*)\.s_(?<session>\w*)/i =~ s
```

After running these two lines, you should have:

```
1.9.3p125 :023 > time
=> "00:09:03" 
1.9.3p125 :024 > domain
 => "domain" 
1.9.3p125 :025 > folder_name
 => "FOLDER_NAME" 
1.9.3p125 :026 > workflow
 => "workflow" 
1.9.3p125 :027 > session
 => "session"
```

You still need to define what characters are allowed for each case and add error handling too.